# Andoird Studio is running ultra slow on Mac

Tags: flutter, performance, android-studio, dart

I'm working on a *Flutter* project and using Android Studio to emulate and edit my code. Every time I'm working on it, Android Studio suddenly freezes for a second or even longer. Indexing takes forever and the overall performance is just weak.
Can someone please help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using M1, check that installed AndroidStudio is for M1(ARM), not Intel.

[image]

Comment: You helped me so much, thank you!!!!!

Comment: Happy to hear that~  :)